# Bash script to send an email in single command line

Tags: linux, shell-script

I to write a bash script to send an email when local host connection is refused and when the connection is open, it should not write an email. For example:

```
netcat -z localhost 8287
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo " Connection refused" |/usr/lib/sendmail -s "Port  doesn't function "  mit@gmail.com
else
  echo "open"
fi
```

When I fire this bash scriptit does't work. I replaced sendmail by mail, sendEmail also, but every time I am getting different errors.

Comment: use /usr/bin/mail. You are not supposed to use sendmail (and anything in /usr/lib/)

Comment: @thanks  Giacomo Catenazzi, I tried that way also but it doesn't give any error and i am not receiving an email as well. I have searched a lot but didn't get any concrete idea.

Comment: So I think your system is not configured to send email outside your host. Check in /var/spool/mail for undelivered mails, or the logs. Install nullmailer or ssmtp (or a complete mta system)

Comment: Add content of your `/var/log/maillog` to your initial post

Answer (score 2):

The following works on my systems:

```
if ! nc -z $host $port; then
    echo "This message intentionally left blank" | mail -s "TCP port $port is not open on $host" $emailaddress
else
    : Do whatever you wanted to do
fi
```

If it doesn't on yours, run `tail -f /var/log/maillog` while you run the script to see why the message might not be getting delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t << EOF
Subject: Port doesn't function
To: mit@gmail.com

Connection refused
EOF
```

Which should be fairly portable (as long as `sendmail` is found in `/usr/lib`, you may want to try a few other locations like `/usr/sbin` or just use `sendmail` for a `$PATH` lookup if it's not there).

`-oi` is to *not* consider a "." on a single line as a terminator (not needed here, but useful in the general case).

On POSIX compliant systems, you should also be able to use `mailx`:

```
echo Connection refused | mailx -s "Port doesn't function" mit@gmail.com
```

All those assume the system has a properly configured mail transfer agent.